# why is the gradle files attributes are not forming perfectly in manifest file java?

Tags: java, gradle

i am building a jar files with lots of dependencies and i am using gradle to package into jar.
When i run the jar i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at Main.firebaseInitalization(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

i am using long list of jar files for packaging and in build.gradle files i have mentioned the jar as folling..

[image]

and more..

i am getting a malformed manifest file as follows

[image]

Because of this i am getting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it this particular way? There are plugins available to create a fat/uber JAR.

Comment: i want the libraries different and dont want it be compiled into my project.